# php sql insert into table

Tags: php, mysql

I am only new in programming and I don't know what the problem in my code. the data that I enter in the tblins are recorded but my data in tbluser won't go in my database. but when i try to remove the insert query for my tblins, the data that I want to enter in tbluser can be recorded in my database. what should I do so that my two tables can record all the data that I'm entering after clicking submit in my page? thanks.

```
$usr="INSERT INTO tbluser(username,password,type) VALUES('".$_POST['txtuname']."','".$_POST['txtpass']."','".$_POST['type']."')";
$ins="INSERT INTO tblins(insLN,insFM,insMN,insadd,insCN,insemail,insbdate) VALUES('".$_POST['txtLN']."','".$_POST['txtFN']."','".$_POST['txtMN']."','".$_POST['txtadd']."','".$_POST['txtCN']."','".$_POST['txtemail']."','".$bdate."')";
```

thanks for all the advice sir. :D I am currently ready on what sql injection is. hope to learn more. :D

here's my full code.

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['txtpass']) && isset($_POST['txtrepass'])){

                    $password1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtpass']);
                    $password2=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtrepass']);

                    if($password1==$password2){



                                $typeopt=$_POST['type'];

                                $bdate=$_POST['year']."-".$_POST['month']."-".$_POST['day'];

                                switch($typeopt){
                                       case 'ins':


                                        $usr=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbluser(username,password,type) VALUES('".$_POST['txtuname']."','".$_POST['txtpass']."','".$_POST['type']."')");

                                        $ins=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblins(insLN,insFM,insMN,insadd,insCN,insemail,insbdate) VALUES('".$_POST['txtLN']."','".$_POST['txtFN']."','".$_POST['txtMN']."','".$_POST['txtadd']."','".$_POST['txtCN']."','".$_POST['txtemail']."','".$bdate."')");


                                        if(mysqli_query($con,$ins)) {
                                            echo"success";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            echo"fail to register";
                                        }

                                        break;

                                        case 'student':
                                        $std="INSERT INTO tblstudent(studLN,studFN,studMN,studBDate,studemail,studadd,studCN)";
                                        $usr="INSERT INTO tbluser(username,password,type)";
                                        $usr=$usr."VALUES('".$_POST['txtuname']."',";
                                        $usr=$usr."'".$_POST['txtpass']."',";
                                        $usr=$usr."'".$_POST['type']."')";

                                        $std=$std."VALUES('".$_POST['txtLN']."',";
                                        $std=$std."'".$_POST['txtFN']."',";
                                        $std=$std."'".$_POST['txtMN']."',";
                                        $std=$std."'".$bdate."',";
                                        $std=$std."'".$_POST['txtemail']."',";
                                        $std=$std."'".$_POST['txtadd']."',";
                                        $std=$std."'".$_POST['txtCN']."')"; 

                                        if(mysqli_query($con,$std)) {
                                            echo"success";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            echo"fail to register";
                                        }

                                }

                    }
                    else{
                        echo"<form>";
                        echo "Password doesn't match. Try registering again.";
                        echo "<input type=submit formaction=register.php value=back>";
                        echo"</form>";
                    }
                }
```

?>

Comment: Can you add the code where you try to write these to the database?

Comment: You should check for any PHP errors or MySQL errors.  There's likely an error message somewhere telling you *exactly* what's wrong.  Also, your code is *wide open* to SQL injection attacks.  You'll want to read and understand this: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: that should be your database connection error. paste your complete code here

Comment: There are numerous things to check but the most likely cause(s) are: misspelled column names, misspelled table name, a column is set to NOT NULL and you are passing it an empty variable, variable length exceeds varchar allowed in DB. Good Luck!

Comment: You're not escaping any of your inputs. Not only does this open you to SQL injection but it could break your SQL. Post the actual SQL being passed to your DB and I bet you see a problem that's not being escaped

Comment: Ouh... send this one to TuteSkool.

Comment: Best advice to be given here is for everyone to supply the OP with tutorial links. There's nothing to do here.

Comment: **OK, here's the scoop:** You are using both `mysqli_query` and `mysql_query` - result: **"fail"**

Comment: Change all `if(mysqli_query($con,$std))` to `if(mysql_query($con,$std))` and try again.

Comment: In your first case "ins", it's not really clear why you have 2 SQL statements but execute only the second one. Did you want to execute both maybe?

Answer (score 3):

First, the way you are building your queries is very prone to errors and SQL Injections.

How about something a little cleaner such as:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) VALUES(:field1,:field2,:field3,:field4,:field5)");
$stmt->execute(array(':field1' => $field1, ':field2' => $field2, ':field3' => $field3, ':field4' => $field4, ':field5' => $field5));
```

And make sure to check error messages.

Comment: what does PDO mean sir?

Comment: @benarylagadan read this as well: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: @benarylagadan [Click here](http://www.phpmysqlitutorials.com/tag/tutorial/) for a basic tutorial on MySQLi - it's' the best advice I can give you. Plus do yourself a favor, use Google and search for `"MySQLi tutorial"`. You will thank me for it ;-)